# Hide element depending on value json in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, ng-hide

I want to hide a div depending on the value I have in the json

for example I have this **{{product.currency}}** and the value can be: £ or € if the value is equal € I want to hide this element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fairly simple with `ng-hide` or the opposite `ng-show` or to not have it in page use `ng-if`

```
<div ng-hide="product.currency =='€'" >
 <!-- or -->
<div ng-show="product.currency !='€'" >
 <!-- or -->
<div ng-if="product.currency !='€'" >
```

And one more alternative, not as elegant or efficient is `ng-switch`.

It is well worth spending a bit of time looking through all the core directives shown in menu on left side of [API reference docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api).